# MySQL Pivot table substring column names

Tags: php, mysql, pivot, truncate

I have a table structure into MySQL databse which looks like this:

**Table data**:

```
Ref  | Var | 3SAa combined % | 3SAa combined of | 3SAa Forward of |3SAa Forward % | 3SAa reverse % | 3SAa Forward of|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AL23    TT   0.00              38.78              48.39             100.0            12.01             85.3
```

My desired output is the folowing:

```
ID   | Ref  |Var |a combined % | a combined of | a Forward of |a Forward % | a reverse % | a Forward of|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3SA   AL23    TT    0.00              38.78         48.39         100.0        12.01             85.3
```

I wanted to know if there is any manner to do it with MySQL. The big issue, I have never found any substring function to truncate column names.

Comment: you only have 1 record in the table ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen, thanks for your reply, no I have severals records in this table.

Comment: `SUBSTR('3SAa combined %' from 6)`

Comment: so, when all records from "3SA" you can easy use SELECT "3SA" as ID, Ref as Ref, Var as Var, `3SAa combined %` as 'a combined %', ..... FROM tablename;  - sorry the fieldnames must in backticks. You cant see it in comment ``````

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, thx for this tip, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @BerndBuffen, sounds pretty dope your solution, what if I have different column names, such as: `124FED combined % | 124FED Forward %` in more?

Comment: Is not crear what you really want. You're talking about substring, but want to change column names. And what does that all have to do with povot table?

Comment: lol - sorry for typos :-)

Comment: @user979974 You can use an alias for every column. Please read the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: Have all your Tables the "same" structure. i mean number of Rows ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen, number of rows of my table can be variable. I didn't manage to trim my column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can test my Querys on your DB. You only must setup the first two vars. The Tablename and a Row number that contains the string.

```
 SET @table_name = 'mytab';
 SET @col_id = 3;

 SELECT DATABASE() INTO @dbname;

 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_NAME,' ' , 1)  INTO @id_name
 FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = @dbname 
   AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name
   AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @col_id;

 SELECT CONCAT('SELECT \'', @id_name, '\' AS Id, ' , GROUP_CONCAT(
     CONCAT( '`',COLUMN_NAME,'`')
     , ' AS `', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,CONCAT(@id_name,' ') , '')
     ,'`\n' ), ' FROM ', @table_name) INTO @sql
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = @dbname 
   AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name
  ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION; 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Test**

```
MariaDB []> SELECT * FROM mytab;
+------+------+-----------------+------------------+
| Ref  | Var  | 3SAa combined % | 3SAa combined of |
+------+------+-----------------+------------------+
| AL23 |      | 0.00            | 38.78            |
+------+------+-----------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>  SET @table_name = 'mytab';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>  SET @col_id = 3;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>  SELECT DATABASE() INTO @dbname;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_NAME,' ' , 1)  INTO @id_name
    ->  FROM information_schema.columns
    ->   WHERE table_schema = @dbname
    ->    AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name
    ->    AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @col_id;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB []>  SELECT CONCAT('SELECT \'', @id_name, '\' AS Id, ' , GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->      CONCAT( '`',COLUMN_NAME,'`')
    ->      , ' AS `', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,CONCAT(@id_name,' ') , '')
    ->      ,'`\n' ), ' FROM ', @table_name) INTO @sql
    ->   FROM information_schema.columns
    ->   WHERE table_schema = @dbname
    ->    AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name
    ->   ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB []> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB []> EXECUTE stmt;
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
| Id   | Ref  | Var  | combined % | combined of |
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
| 3SAa | AL23 |      | 0.00       | 38.78       |
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks so much for your script. I have actually this error when I am trying to execute:`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO @id_name
FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = @dbname ' at line 1`

Comment: sorry, i cant see the error. I have copied it from my post into the client and its works. Can you post the Query please

Comment: in the query, I just changed as you adviced to me, tablename:`SET @table_name = 'run09022016'; SET @col_id = 3;` and I let `@col_id` to 3. I have now this error: `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql`=>`#1054 - Unknown column 'Reference' in 'field list'`

Comment: ahhhh, so please execute SELECT @sql before the Prepare statement and post the output

Comment: I added `SELECT @sql` before the prepare statement, like so:`SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;` I have this in output:`PREPARE stmt FROM @sql`=>`#1054 - Unknown column 'Reference' in 'field list'`

Comment: my mistake, dont execute the prepare, execute and deallocate statement. execute only SELECT @sql; instead of PREPARE to see the generatet sql Statement and post this.

Comment: I did as you adviced me, i executed only SELECT @sql. No errors in output, it displays:`@sql =>  
SELECT 'Status' AS Id, Reference AS Reference`

Comment: have your table only 2 Columns ? Please create this table and test the script with mytab: CREATE TABLE `mytab` (
  `Ref` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Var` ENUM('blue','green') DEFAULT NULL,
  `3SAa combined %` VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `3SAa combined of` VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ref`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `mytab` (`Ref`, `Var`, `3SAa combined %`, `3SAa combined of`)
VALUES
 ('AL23', '', '0.00', '38.78');

Comment: mytab created. No errors in output while I execute ur script into phpmyadmin, but I have nothing displayed as your test, so i cannot see the result but that the query was performed with no errors. In my runtable I have more than 2 columns, do u thing this issue is coming from that?

Comment: now - dont execute DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; this removes your resultset. DEALOCATE must be run after you have get/seen your result. Its free the memory from prepare

Comment: I removed DEALOCATE, I just have in my phpmyadmin OK, 1 row affected, but nothing else is showed despite I let `EXECUTE stmt;`

Comment: can you use a normal mysql client to test. I cant check it in phpmyadmin

Comment: yeah it works with mysql normal client. That's odd that it doesn't return any output with phpmyadmin. Thanks alot @BerndBuffen for your help.